# How to run an apk in another application

Tags: java, android, containers, apk, television

I have made several tv apps. Now Im making a container app which may launch all those apps. But the restriction here is that i dont want user to separately download those tv apps. I have the apks of all those tv apps. How can i make my container app run those apks so that they would launch within my container app. Technologies I'm using:

1. Android Studio
2. Java
3. API Level 21

Let me explain my question again:
**1) Have a container app
2) have several apks
3) Want to run those apks in that container app**

Comment: Install those APKs, then have UI in your app to launch activities in those apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, even with Root there aren't really apps that can "execute" apks.

You have 3 options:

1. Install all those apps beforehand (or manually) and then try to
   launch them with Intents, same way you would launch other apps on
   the phone.
2. Include all apps you mentioned within the app, if you are not a
   beginner you could also look at Firebase Dynamic Modules which might
   make sense here (unless those modules are small, then just include
   them)
3. If this fits your usecase: You can show multiple Launcher icons/
   Have multiple Launchable activities.

So you can install your app, and then have 3+1 apps shown in the launcher. Your app can still launch the other apps because those are your app. You see this with the phone/contacts app which is the same app, but still shows as 2 in the launcher.

In general, if you want a container app for apks, you have other/better options. Container apps aren't allowed because for one they would make viruses easier.

Comment: So according to your pt 2, instead of apk's i should make separate modules of those apps and then launch them in my container app. But those are full fledged iptv and ott which may not fit as a tiny module.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but yes. 
To be honest, unless you have another reason to do this (and if this is one of your first apps) I would just put the modules inside. Even banking apps are 60MB+, if you are under it I'd just disable that parts in code. You can use Firebase dynamic modules later if you want.   You can also make it more modularized by really putting those parts into modules, makes it easier for Firebase and later in case other apps use the same parts/modules

Comment: I somewhat disagree with this. It is possible. Virtual Android is able to do it: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pspace.vandroid